# A Software to Check bad emails in Salesforce

Tags: community

Is there an app exchange that can check bad email addresses in Salesforce so that we can eliminate those contacts or mark them as bad email addresses flag. The cheaper the better.

Comment: bad email addresses?

Answer (score 1):

We have similar considerations.  There are services that you can send your emails to and have them verify if the email addresses are valid.  The better ones do it without sending an email.  Just google it and you will find them.

The other option is to just send an email from salesforce and salesforce will identify a bounceback.  It will show on the contact or lead record near the email address that there is something the matter with it.